# Class variable not available into Mailable build() method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I am working on a Laravel application where I am setting up custom email verification storing token in my database. For that I have two controllers, one is `UserController` where I have function to register a user which calls another controller. The another controller is `EmailVerificationController` where I have a static function `sendEmail` that receives a `User` object, generates a token, stores in database, attaches the token in `User` object and passes it to a mailable. I have a Mailable `UserRegistered` which receives the `User` object in its constructor and is assigned to a protected class variable. I am using a Job `SendEmail` to send the emails which receives a Mailable object and the recipient email address.

Controller `UserController`

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
     // Validate request
     // Create user
     $user = User::create($request_data);
     // Here the $user has two attributes firstname and lastname
     // I have skipped other several attributes for ease
     EmailVerificationController::sendEmail($user);
}
```

Controller `EmailVerificationController`

```
public static function sendEmail(User $user)
{
     // Generate a token $token and store it into the database
     // Appending token into user object
     $user->token = $token;
     // Here the $user has three attributes firstname, lastname and token
     SendEmail::dispatch(new UserRegistered($user), $user->email);
}
```

Job `SendEmail`

```
class SendEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected Mailable $mail;
    protected string $recipient;

    public function __construct(Mailable $mail, string $recipient)
    {
        $this->mail = $mail;
        $this->recipient = $recipient;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // Send email
        Mail::to($this->recipient)->send($this->mail);
    }
}
```

Mailable `UserRegistered`

```
class UserRegistered extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        Log::info($this->user);
        // Logging $this->user here gives me firstname, lastname and token i.e. all attributes.
    }

    public function build()
    {
        Log::info($this->user);
        // Logging $this->user here gives me firstname and lastname only but not the token
    
        return $this->subject('Registration successful')
                    ->view('emails.user_registered')
                    ->with([
                        'firstname' => $this->user->firstname,
                        'token' => $this->user->token
                    ]);
    }
}
```

Model `User` - with all attributes

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'email',
        'photo',
        'role',
        'password',
        'verified',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

The problem I am facing here is, inside the `build()` function of Mailable `UserRegistered` I am not getting the appended token. Due to which the token is not available in my view. But when I log the `User` object inside the Mailable constructor, I can see the token there.

Is there any core programming concept that I am missing here or am I doing anything in a wrong way?

Comment: Can you show your User model, please?

Comment: @aynber I have updated it in the question.

Comment: The User model is being serialized when passed to the UserRegistered class. Basically the user object is converted to an array when the email is pushed to the queue, then fetched again from the database using the id when the job is run and because of this the token property you've set is not maintained as it does not exist on the base User class. I would suggest you pass the token as the second parameter of the UserRegistered class instead

Comment: @Jab73 It works this way. I fairly understood the flow when a job is sent to the queue. Still, could you please make it clearer and write it as an answer?